# How to access files from a certain php page that are protected by htaccess?

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

I have a page ( example : http://mypage.com/getfiles.php ) where the user can enter a keycode
and then the page generates the links( html http://mypage.com/download/myfile.zip) to the files zu download and the user can click on the links to get the files.

The problem is that the files are stored in a folder ( download ) which is protected so nobody can directly access the files under http://mypage.com/download/myfile.zip.

I tried some differnt thinks i read on the internet to change the .htaccess file to alow access from a certain page... but it didn't work !

So I have 2 Questions :
1. Is this the easiest way ? Or is it better to use another way to give the user access to the files ( filesize from 50mb to 500mb )
2. If the idea to customize the .htaccess file is the best way whats wrong with it ?

```
# set an environtment variable "noauth" if the request starts with certain string
SetEnvIf Request_URI "^http://mypage.com/getfiles.php" noauth=1

AuthType Basic
AuthName "Access to /download"
AuthUserFile ****
Require user ****

# Here is where we allow/deny
Order Deny,Allow
Satisfy any
Deny from all
Require valid-user
Allow from env=noauth
```

Or do i have to guide the user to an php script which forwards him to the file, because with link it doesn't work ?

Thank you very much !

Comment: Why don't you just append the keycode to url, and check if its valid and download the file, otherwise don't?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create an script say **download.php** under http://mypage.com/ which eventaully copy content from file **"download/myfile.zip"** and auto download it to the user.

**Example code:**

```
// Add some keycode security, then download file for user.

$file_url = 'download/myfile.zip';
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary"); 
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . basename($file_url) . "\""); 
readfile($file_url); // do the double-download-dance (dirty but worky)
```

Comment: I have one more question :) as i see the readfile has the comment "// do the double-download-dance (dirty but worky)" ... can you explain the double-download-dance ? It sounds like its not an efficient way :) will it be a problem because i have some large files ( 100 - 500mb )?

Comment: haha no it will not, because zip files are directly downloadable but since you have security issues, the code will download file for you not the web server itself, so double-download thing :)

Answer (score 1):

1. Let this basic authentication be "as is" for someone who directly comes to `/download` folder.
2. Make these changes in `getfiles.php`. Rather than giving direct link to `zip` file you can generate a link like this:

   1. Validate `keycode` and store it in session.
   2. If `keycode` is valid generate a download link: `http://mypage.com/files.php?path=/download/myfile.zip`
   3. Inside a new file `files.php` check if session has valid `keycode`. If yes then access the file using PHP file operations with correct `Content-Type` header.